# Ruby Regular expressions (regex): character appear only once at most

Tags: ruby, regex

Suppose I want to make sure a string x equals any combination of abcd (each character appearing one or zero times-->each character should not repeat, but the combination may appear in any order)

1. valid ex: bc .. abcd ... bcad ... b... d .. dc
2. invalid ex. abcdd, cc, bbbb, abcde (ofcourse)

my effort:
I tried various techniques: 
the closest I came was 
x =~ **^(((a)?(b)?(c)?(d)?))$**

but this wont work if I do not type them in the same order as i have written:

1. works for: ab, acd, abcd, a, d, c
2. wont work for: bcda, cb, da (anything that is not in the above order)

you can test your solutions here : http://rubular.com/r/wCpD355bub

PS: the characters may not be in alphabetical order, it could be   u c  e t

Comment: You have bcab as valid in your example.  Did you mean for the b to repeat?  I thought that would be invalid based on the rest of your description.

Comment: yes, that was a mistake from my part. thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is really not what regular expressions are meant to do, but if you really really want to.

Here is a regex that satisfies the conditions.

```
^([a-d])(?!(\1))([a-d])?(?!(\1|\3))([a-d])?(?!(\1|\3|\5))([a-d])?(?!(\1|\3|\5|\7))$
```

basically it goes through each character, making the group, then makes sure that that group isn't matched. Then checks the next character, and makes sure that group and the previous groups don't match.

Comment: I had two typos, missing some `|`.  Fixed now

Comment: Now, it does ***not*** match `"acd"`.

Comment: Bah, I didn't see that it was supposed to match less

Comment: Ok, revised... again :) Works for less than 4 characters now

Comment: Do it again but lets see what it'd look like for `a-g`.

Comment: It looks the same, just switch `[a-d]` for `[a-g]`

Answer (score 5):

If you can use things besides regexes, you can try:

```
str.chars.uniq.length == str.length && str.match(/^[a-d]+$/)
```

The general idea here is that you just strip any duplicated characters from the string, and if the length of the uniq array is not equal to the length of the source string, you have a duplicated character in the string. The regex then enforces the character set.

This can probably be improved, but it's pretty straightforward. It does create a couple of extra arrays, so you might want a different approach if this needs to be used in a performance-critical location.

If you want to stick to regexes, you could use:

```
str.match(/^[a-d]+$/) && !str.match(/([a-d]).*\1/)
```

That'll basically check that the string only contains the allowed characters, and that those characters are never repeated.

Comment: I like this because of its brevity.  It would be not so optimal at large strings, though.

Comment: If you are expecting only lowercase alpha strings, you can automatically eliminate any string over 26 characters long, since it will have to repeat a character.

Comment: If the character set to match against contains duplicates, then the input can be more than 26 characters ;)

Comment: Right, but you know that any string >26 characters long must contain duplicates, so you can reject it as valid without doing any further analysis on it. This gets around the "big string" problem by ensuring that you only ever have to do the more expensive work on small strings.

Comment: Unicode, too?  It's interesting what problems an optimization produces.  That's why I like all of the various answers to general questions like this one.  +1.

Comment: Well, your max string length will be the size of your valid character set. Unicode "only" has 95,221 valid characters - the array operation still works decently quickly even on strings of that size.

Answer (score 2):

You can reverse it (match the condition that would make it fail)

```
re = /^ # start of line
(?=.*([a-d]).*\1) # match if a letter appears more than once
| # or
(?=.*[^a-d]) # match if a non abcd char appears
/x
puts 'fail' if %w{bc abcd bcad b d dc}.any?{|s| s =~ re}
puts 'fail' unless %w{abcdd cc bbbb abcde}.all?{|s| s =~ re}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think regexes are well suited to this problem, so here is another non-regex solution.  It's recursive:

```
def match_chars_no_more_than_once(characters, string)
  return true if string.empty?
  if characters.index(string[0]) 
    match_chars_no_more_than_once(characters.sub(string[0],''), string[1..-1])
  else
    false
  end
end

%w{bc bdac hello acbbd cdda}.each do |string|
  p [string, match_chars_no_more_than_once('abcd', string)]
end
```

Output:

```
["bc", true]
["bdac", true]
["hello", false]
["acbbd", false]
["cdda", false]
```

Comment: For four characters this is reasonable, but larger allowed character sets will really wind up the stack. Imagine what would happen if the Unicode character set was allowed.

Comment: This algorithm would not do well at all!  This question is essentially about a variation on search with breadcrumbs.  As evidenced here, there are many approaches, and each one has implicit assumptions that force tradeoffs.  That's what makes the answers interesting, in my opinion.